# Python: Get URL path sections

Tags: python, url

How do I get specific path sections from a url? For example, I want a function which operates on this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/hithere?image=2934
```

and returns "hithere"

or operates on this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/hithere/something/else
```

and returns the same thing ("hithere")

I know this will probably use urllib or urllib2 but I can't figure out from the docs how to get only a section of the path.

Comment: The URL syntax is something like: `scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id`, so 'hithere' is the whole `path` in the first case and 1 section of the it in the second. Just urlparse it then 'hithere' is going to be path.split('/')[1]

Comment: wouldn't it be  `path.split('/')[0]`? (the first item of the list)

Comment: No, because the path starts with a '/' so [0] is an empty string. I.e. http://ideone.com/hJRxk

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Extract the path component of the URL with [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) (Python 2.7):

```py
import urlparse
path = urlparse.urlparse('http://www.example.com/hithere/something/else').path
print path
> '/hithere/something/else'
```

or [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) (Python 3):

```py
import urllib.parse
path = urllib.parse.urlparse('http://www.example.com/hithere/something/else').path).path
print(path)
> '/hithere/something/else'
```

---

Split the path into components with [os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split):

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.split(path)
('/hithere/something', 'else')
```

The dirname and basename functions give you the two pieces of the split; perhaps use dirname in a while loop:

```
>>> while os.path.dirname(path) != '/':
...     path = os.path.dirname(path)
... 
>>> path
'/hithere'
```

Comment: Does urllib not have any function that can do this without doing a bunch of string parsing/splitting/looping? I thought there'd be a shortcut...

Comment: how does urlparse.parse compare with cgi.parse?

Comment: urlparse.parse didn't work (at least on Python 2.7). You should use urlparse.urlparse

Comment: Don't use os.path.split for urls as it is platform dependent. That code will fail on Windows because it expects \ as a delimiter!

Comment: @Viorel This is incorrect. I just tested. It would be wrong to use `os.path.join` since it would use the wrong delimiter, but the `split` method can still split on `/`. In fact, you can type all your directory paths for Windows using `/` as the directory separator in Python. Using `/` as the directory separator works in a lot of places on Windows, not just in Python.

Comment: os.path.split may happen to work but I think it would be bad practice to use it here, as it is clearly intended for os paths and not url paths.

Comment: using `os.path` will fail for URLs containing \ on Windows. Use `posixpath` instead - see my answer.

Comment: Why not just use `path.split("/")`?

Comment: `filter(bool, path.split("/"))`, in case there is a trailing "/" char

Answer (score 51):

Python 3.4+ solution:

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote, urlparse
from pathlib import PurePosixPath

url = 'http://www.example.com/hithere/something/else'

PurePosixPath(
    unquote(
        urlparse(
            url
        ).path
    )
).parts[1]

# returns 'hithere' (the same for the URL with parameters)

# parts holds ('/', 'hithere', 'something', 'else')
#               0    1          2            3
```

Answer (score 26):

The best option is to use the [`posixpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/undoc.html) module when working with the path component of URLs. This module has the same interface as [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) and consistently operates on POSIX paths when used on POSIX and Windows NT based platforms.

---

Sample Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.parse
import sys
import posixpath
import ntpath
import json

def path_parse( path_string, *, normalize = True, module = posixpath ):
    result = []
    if normalize:
        tmp = module.normpath( path_string )
    else:
        tmp = path_string
    while tmp != "/":
        ( tmp, item ) = module.split( tmp )
        result.insert( 0, item )
    return result

def dump_array( array ):
    string = "[ "
    for index, item in enumerate( array ):
        if index > 0:
            string += ", "
        string += "\"{}\"".format( item )
    string += " ]"
    return string

def test_url( url, *, normalize = True, module = posixpath ):
    url_parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse( url )
    path_parsed = path_parse( urllib.parse.unquote( url_parsed.path ),
        normalize=normalize, module=module )
    sys.stdout.write( "{}\n  --[n={},m={}]-->\n    {}\n".format( 
        url, normalize, module.__name__, dump_array( path_parsed ) ) )

test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/something/else" )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/something/else/" )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/something/else/", normalize = False )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/../else" )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/../else", normalize = False )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/../../else" )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/../../else", normalize = False )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/something/./else" )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/something/./else", normalize = False )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/something/./else/./" )
test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere/something/./else/./", normalize = False )

test_url( "http://eg.com/see%5C/if%5C/this%5C/works", normalize = False )
test_url( "http://eg.com/see%5C/if%5C/this%5C/works", normalize = False,
    module = ntpath )
```

---

Code output:

```
http://eg.com/hithere/something/else
  --[n=True,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "something", "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/something/else/
  --[n=True,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "something", "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/something/else/
  --[n=False,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "something", "else", "" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/../else
  --[n=True,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/../else
  --[n=False,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "..", "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/../../else
  --[n=True,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/../../else
  --[n=False,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "..", "..", "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/something/./else
  --[n=True,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "something", "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/something/./else
  --[n=False,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "something", ".", "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/something/./else/./
  --[n=True,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "something", "else" ]
http://eg.com/hithere/something/./else/./
  --[n=False,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "hithere", "something", ".", "else", ".", "" ]
http://eg.com/see%5C/if%5C/this%5C/works
  --[n=False,m=posixpath]-->
    [ "see\", "if\", "this\", "works" ]
http://eg.com/see%5C/if%5C/this%5C/works
  --[n=False,m=ntpath]-->
    [ "see", "if", "this", "works" ]
```

---

Notes:

- On Windows NT based platforms [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) is [`ntpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/undoc.html)
- On Unix/Posix based platforms [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) is [`posixpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/undoc.html)
- [`ntpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/undoc.html) will not handle backslashes (`\`) correctly (see last two cases in code/output) - which is why [`posixpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/undoc.html) is recommended.
- remember to use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)
- consider using [`posixpath.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)
- The semantics of multiple path separators (`/`) is not defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). However, [`posixpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/undoc.html) collapses multiple adjacent path separators  (i.e. it treats `///`, `//` and `/` the same)
- Even though POSIX and URL paths have similar syntax and semantics, they are not identical.

---

Normative References:

- [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 - Vol. 1: Base Definitions - Section 4.12: Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12)
- [The GNU C Library Reference Manual - Section 11.2: File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Names.html#File-Names)
- [IETF RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax - Section 3.3: Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)
- [IETF RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax - Section 6: Normalization and Comparison](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6)
- [Wikipedia: URL normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization)

Comment: Python 3.4+ solution: `url_path = PurePosixPath(urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.urlparse(url‌​).path))`.

Comment: @Navin worthwhile to post this as an answer

Comment: Great answer.
However this fails if there is an error in one of the scrapped url.

For example: `test_url( "http://eg.com/hithere//something/else" )` will lead to an infinite loop on `while tmp != "/":`

Answer (score 10):

Note in Python3 import has changed to `from urllib.parse import urlparse` See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#url-parsing). Here is an example:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url = 's3://bucket.test/my/file/directory'
>>> p = urlparse(url)
>>> p
ParseResult(scheme='s3', netloc='bucket.test', path='/my/file/directory', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> p.scheme
's3'
>>> p.netloc
'bucket.test'
>>> p.path
'/my/file/directory'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import urlparse

output = urlparse.urlparse('http://www.example.com/temp/something/happen/index.html').path

output

'/temp/something/happen/index.html'

Split the path -- inbuilt rpartition func of string 

output.rpartition('/')[0]

'/temp/something/happen'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using urlparse and [rpartition](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/rpartition).

```
# Python 2x:
from urlparse import urlparse
# Python 3x:
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def printPathTokens(full_url):
    print('printPathTokens() called: %s' % full_url)

    p_full = urlparse(full_url).path

    print(' . p_full url: %s' % p_full)

    # Split the path using rpartition method of string
    # rpartition "returns a tuple containing the part the before separator,
    # argument string and the part after the separator" 
    (rp_left, rp_match, rp_right) = p_full.rpartition('/')

    if rp_match == '': # returns the rpartition separator if found
        print(' . No slashes found in path')
    else:
        print(' . path to last resource: %s' % rp_left)
        if rp_right == '': # Ended with a slash
            print(' . last resource: (none)')
        else:
            print(' . last resource: %s' % (rp_right))


printPathTokens('http://www.example.com/temp/something/happen/index.html')
# Output:
# printPathTokens() called: http://www.example.com/temp/something/happen/index.html
# . p_full url: /temp/something/happen/index.html
# . path to last resource: /temp/something/happen
# . last resource: index.html

printPathTokens('http://www.example.com/temp/something/happen/')
# Output:
# printPathTokens() called: http://www.example.com/temp/something/happen/
# . p_full url: /temp/something/happen/
# . path to last resource: /temp/something/happen
# . last resource: (none)

printPathTokens('http://www.example.com/temp/something/happen')
# Output:
# printPathTokens() called: http://www.example.com/temp/something/happen
# . p_full url: /temp/something/happen
# . path to last resource: /temp/something
# . last resource: happen
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) and [os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) will do the trick. The following script stores all sections of a url in a list, backwards.

```
import os.path, urlparse

def generate_sections_of_url(url):
    path = urlparse.urlparse(url).path
    sections = []; temp = "";
    while path != '/':
        temp = os.path.split(path)
        path = temp[0]
        sections.append(temp[1])
    return sections
```

This would return: ["else", "something", "hithere"]