# Regex Python: Get Page and Subpage from URL

Tags: python, regex

I'm sorry I'm pretty noob with regex since long time.

How can I get from this kind of string /projects/myproject/, the 2 following elements (**projects** , **myproject**) ?

Output :

```
print group1 : 'projects'

print group2 : 'myproject'
```

Thanks

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  What language are you using? You probably don't want to use a regex, but rather an existing module that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

If you're using PHP, you want the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


If you're using Perl, you want the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module.

If you're using Ruby, use the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module.

Comment: I'm using Python, I've noticed it in my post title :)

Comment: I know, but I don't know what Python uses.  Point is, there are existing written, tested and debugged tools out there for you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894384/python-get-url-path-sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_str = "/projects/myproject/"
matches = re.findall("/(.+?)/(.+)/",my_str)
print matches  #prints ['projects','myproject']
```

Comment: your regex is working, but this is what I get :
[('projects', 'targetstuffscholarships/')]

1) The last "/" is still here
2) How can I get an array because it's actually a list in an array

Thanks

Comment: `matches` is an array of strings that the regex matched. Not an array of arrays. And, can you show us the string you are matching against?

Comment: The string is : /projects/targetstuffscholarships/

Comment: I'm not getting an array of array but a list included in an array. The parenthesis in my output means that is actually a list

Comment: `matches[0]` is what you are after. You can access your matches like `matches[0][0]` and `matches[0][1]`

Comment: First probleme resolved :) but still in a list. logging.info(type(matches)) output <type 'list'>.
Anyway, I'll accepted the response as you rocks, I'll find out how to convert this list to an array :)

Comment: @socrateisabot Arrays in python is called List. They are not two different things. You are getting a list of tuples, not an array of lists. Read my previous comment.