# Regex to parse out a part of URL using python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, regex-negation

I am having data as follows,

```
data['url']
http://hostname.com/aaa/uploads/2013/11/a-b-c-d.jpg https://www.aaa.com/
http://hostname.com/bbb/uploads/2013/11/e-f-g-h.gif https://www.aaa.com/
http://hostname.com/ccc/uploads/2013/11/e-f-g-h.png http://hostname.com/ccc/uploads/2013/11/a-a-a-a.html 
http://hostname.com/ddd/uploads/2013/11/w-e-r-t.ico
http://hostname.com/ddd/uploads/2013/11/r-t-y-u.aspx https://www.aaa.com/
http://hostname.com/bbb/uploads/2013/11/t-r-w-q.jpeg https://www.aaa.com/
```

I want to find out the formats such as .jpg, .gif, .png, .ico, .aspx, .html, .jpeg and parse it out backwards until it finds a "/". Also I want to check for several occurance all through the string. My output should be,

```
data['parsed']
a-b-c-d
e-f-g-h
e-f-g-h a-a-a-a
w-e-r-t
r-t-y-u
t-r-w-q
```

I am thinking instead of writing individual commands for each of the formats, is there a way to write everything under a single command.

Can anybody help me in writing for theses commands? I am new to regex and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Get URL path sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894384/python-get-url-path-sections)

Comment: Must this be done with regex? `urlparse` (as noted in the possible duplicate) does the job splendidly.

Comment: @JIm YEs. I have sevaral conditions like this and the URL is not structured enough to parse through urlparse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
data['parse'] = re.findall(r'[^/]+\.[a-z]+ ',data['url'])
```

That will pick out all of the file names with their extensions. If you want to remove the extensions, the code above returns a list which you can then process with list comprehension and re.sub like so:

```
[re.sub('\.[a-z]+$','',exp) for exp in data['parse']]
```

Use the .join function to create a string as demonstrated in Totem's answer

Answer (score 1):

this builds a list of name to extension pairs

```
import re
results = []
for link in data:
    matches = re.search(r'/(\w-\w-\w-\w)\.(\w{2,})\b', link)
    results.append((matches.group(1), matches.group(2)))
```

Comment: it doesnt work for 4 letters such as jpeg, aspx, html

Comment: removed the extension char limit

Answer (score 1):

This pattern returns the file names. I have just used one of your urls to demonstrate, for more, you could simply append the matches to a list of results:

```
import re
url = "http://hostname.com/ccc/uploads/2013/11/e-f-g-h.png http://hostname.com/ccc/uploads/2013/11/a-a-a-a.html" 

p = r'((?:[a-z]-){3}[a-z]).'
matches = re.findall(p, url)

>>> print('\n'.join(matches))
e-f-g-h
a-a-a-a
```

There is the assumption that the urls all have the general form you provided.