# urllib: Get name of file from direct download link

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, request, urllib

**Python 3.** Probably need to use urllib to do this,

I need to know how to send a request to a direct download link, and get the name of the file it attempts to save.

(As an example, a KSP mod from CurseForge: https://kerbal.curseforge.com/projects/mechjeb/files/2355387/download)

Of course, the file ID (`2355387`) will be changed. It could be from any project, but always on CurseForge. (If that makes a difference on the way it's downloaded.)

That example link results in the file:

[image: Download Screenshot]

How can I return that file name in Python?

**Edit:** I should note that I want to avoid saving the file, reading the name, then deleting it if possible. That seems like the worst way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [**`urllib.request`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request), when you request a response from a url, the response contains a reference to the url you are downloading.

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen    
>>> url = 'https://kerbal.curseforge.com/projects/mechjeb/files/2355387/download'
>>> response = urlopen(url)
>>> response.url
'https://addons-origin.cursecdn.com/files/2355/387/MechJeb2-2.6.0.0.zip'
```

You can use [**`os.path.basename`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to get the filename:

```
>>> from os.path import basename
>>> basename(response.url)
'MechJeb2-2.6.0.0.zip'
```

Comment: It also seems odd to me that `os.path` works on a URL. Is this intended or merely an inadvertent benefit?

Comment: See the answers to [**Get URL path sections**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894384/python-get-url-path-sections). More generally you might want to use a combination of [**`urlparse`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) and **`posixpath`**.

Answer (score 4):

```
from urllib import request

url = 'file download link'
filename = request.urlopen(request.Request(url)).info().get_filename()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This answer does not always work. For example, I get `None` for `filename` when setting `url` to "https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz"

Comment: Adding onto my previous comment: `urlopen` returns a http.client.HTTPResponse. According to the bottom of https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpmessage-objects, it is implemented using the email.message.Message class (https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_filename). That's where the `get_filename` method comes from. It uses the Content-Disposition HTTP header, which may not be always there. That's why it doesn't always work.