# How to get file name and type from a URL with downloadable content?

Tags: python

Here is a link to a sample excel file : [Sample excel file](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962)

When we hit this URL in a browser, it automatically fetches the name and extension, example in case of the above URL it's **Financial Sample.xlsx**

How can I get this information using Python?

I'm saving this file using `urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962", "Newname.extension")`

The above works fine, i.e. when I provide a custom name before saving. However, I want the original name and extension.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer from this [Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150478/urllib-get-name-of-file-from-direct-download-link/43150676)

```
from os.path import basename
from urllib.request import urlopen    
url = 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962'
response = urlopen(url)
response.url
basename(response.url)
```

The `basename(response.url)` returns **Financial Sample.xlsx**. This works because the URL automatically redirects to a real URL, which contains the file name.