# How to get the file name from a link before downloading the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redirect, python-requests, urllib

For example I have [a link](http://booksdl.org/get.php?md5=5c9afff27ee041c34c698d62bd510616&key=D3JE34WPUY7LQ11U) and I want to know the file name before I start the download.

There are many questions like this, but they all boil down to extracting the file name from the link. What should I do when file name is not in the link?

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150478/urllib-get-name-of-file-from-direct-download-link), but it is not working in my situation. I keep get the same link I passed to `urlopen()` instead of the direct link to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, you can use the following:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> url = 'http://booksdl.org/get.php?md5=5c9afff27ee041c34c698d62bd510616&key=D3JE34WPUY7LQ11U'
>>> response = urlopen(url)
>>> response.headers.get_filename()
'[Progress in Mathematics 244] Michael Atiyah (auth.), Pavel Etingof, Vladimir Retakh, I. M. Singer (eds.) - The Unity of Mathematics_ In Honor of the Ninetieth Birthday of I.M. Gelfand (2006, BirkhÃ¤user Basel).pdf'
```

Comment: I tried your code. It is not working. `response.headers.get_filename()` return nothing. Then I try `response.url` and find that it redirect me to [this link](http://libgen.lc/ads.php?md5=5c9afff27ee041c34c698d62bd510616&key=D3JE34WPUY7LQ11U)

Comment: @gagalady since posting this answer the original link has changed to redirect to the page in your comment. As it no longer points to a download link, the code will no longer work, but should work for a valid link.