# is there a way to get the name of the file from urls like this in python?

Tags: python, url, download

i wanna get the exact name of the file from links like this :
https://dl.yasdl.com/2021/Android/Bazaar.14.1.0_YasDL.com.apk?aqqr

and the result i want is this :
Bazaar.14.1.0_YasDL.com.apk

this is a download link of a file and i want to return the exact name of the file that is been downloading. i would like to have a general way to extract name. the other solutions like splitext function doesn't work in this format. by the way the extra part at the end of the url can be changed.("?aqqr" in this case)
something like this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8yQt.png)

thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894384/python-get-url-path-sections

Comment: @DhanaD thanks but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
path="https://dl.yasdl.com/2021/Android/Bazaar.14.1.0_YasDL.com.apk?aqqr"
firstpos=path.rfind("/")
lastpos= path.rfind("?")
print(path[firstpos+1: lastpos])
```

Comment: i want a general way to do it. the last part is not always the same.

Comment: Do u want split the last part from '?' onwards?.  I just edited the code..  is it fine?