# Grab last url parameter in referer

Tags: python, django

Is there a way without actually parsing the data wit a custom function to get the last piece of a url in django?

so if the url looks like this

```
http://192.168.1.100/test/article/1
```

And i just want to be able to grab the 1 without actually having query paramaters in the url.

Comment: Can you please share the url pattern

Comment: path('article/<int:cid>', views.article_details, name='article_details'),

Comment: What exactly is your usecase? 
If you want to avoid `<int:cid>` in the urls.py, then Django will not be able to match the url unless you hardcode it somehow.

Comment: You could try a combination of `urlparse` and `os.path.split`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7894483/9313033 . For example `os.path.split(urlparse(url).path)[-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to do this in template u can use just `cut` filter:

```
{{ request.path | cut: "/article/" }}
```

but if u want get those id for example in a view, u can use python split:

```
url.split('/')[-1]
```

u gave to less info to propose make it in the better way :)